# On Standalone Tomcat server how much higher value - maxThreads and maxConnections can be set?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, webserver, tomcat7

I am using tomcat server for webservice and found two properties maxThreads and maxConnections defined as in : 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Now, Point to raise here, suppose I have server with 10 CPUs and 10G RAM, then how many concurrent connections could be triggered from UI. And how will I decide what  will be maximum value for  maxThreads and maxConnections  for single tomcat cluster?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if your Tomcat in NIO (more connection, less threads) or BIO (one thread for connection - this is the default in Tomcat 7) mode.

Let's say that in default mode you can try to set maxThread attribute up to 500-700 and maxConnection to 10000.

Comment: suppose my design supports BIO , then according to my server size, what would be the suggested numbers? set maxThread attribute up to 500-700 and maxConnection to 10000. Looks not feasable.